# How to setup resource/:id with RestKit

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

My Restful API:

```
GET http://example.com/articles
GET http://example.com/articles/:id
...
```

Heres my descriptor setup:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorArticleList = [RKResponseDescriptor
                                responseDescriptorWithMapping:articleMapping
                                method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                pathPattern:@"/articles"
                                keyPath:@nil     
                                statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorArticle = [RKResponseDescriptor
                               responseDescriptorWithMapping:articleMapping
                               method:RKRequestMethodGET
                               pathPattern:@"/articles/:id"
                               keyPath:nil
                               statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
```

Function for (GET) http://example.com/articles works

```
[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/articles"
                    parameters:nil
                    success:^sucess{...} failure:^failue{...}];
```

Function for (GET) http://example.com/articles/:id doesn't work

```
//Whatever Object is article object or article.id, it doesn't work
[objectManager getObject:Object path:@"/articles/:id"
                    parameters:nil 
                    success:^sucess{...} failure:^failue{...}];
```

Server console displays:

```
GET /articles/:id 404 117ms
```

Obviously it didn't replace /:id with article.id

I browsed the RestKit documents and examples which looks not updated for 0.20.x, and didn't find the answer. I would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacements aren't always made into the path pattern. In particular, when calling `getObject:path:parameters:success:failure:` RestKit is expecting a path, not a path pattern so it will not attempt to replace anything. Your response descriptor is fine, path patterns are always checked there.

`getObject:path:parameters:success:failure:` will inject into a path pattern if the object is supplied and no path is supplied (path must be `nil`). In this case the object manager will look for a router which matches the class of the object and the `GET` request type. So, you need to add a router, something like:

```
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[...Article class] pathPattern:@"/articles/:id" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
```